# Debug a daemon in RubyMine

Tags: ruby, debugging, daemon

Is there any way to debug a daemon in Ruby Mine. The way I am calling this file is like this

Daemons.run(file, options)

where file is the name of file and options is the bunch of options that I am passing to the file.

Comment: which version of rubymine are you using...?

Answer (score -1):

I'm also trying to debug a Rails daemon (gem daemons). The ActiveMessaging poller script in particular. However the ruby-debug-ide fails to attach due to various reasons (race conditions, etc).

The solution I came up with is to use gem rails-daemons. This works with ActiveMessaging and allows to me to create all kinds of daemons, and importantly, be able to debug them in RubyMine

**Workaround**

Use https://github.com/mirasrael/daemons-rails to create a new daemon. This works with RubyMine 6.3.3, Rails 4, Ruby 2.1.2 on OSX 10.8.x

**Sample Daemon**

### mqpoller.rb (after running rails generate daemon mqpoller)

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

# You might want to change this
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= "development"

root = File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))
root = File.dirname(root) until File.exists?(File.join(root, 'config'))
Dir.chdir(root)

require File.join(root, "config", "environment")

$running = true
Signal.trap("TERM") do 
  $running = false
end

while($running) do

    # Replace this with your code
    Rails.logger.auto_flushing = true
    Rails.logger.info "This daemon is still running at #{Time.now}.\n"

    # ADDED MY CODE BELOW HERE TO START ActiveMessaging

    Rails.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
    ActiveMessaging.logger = Rails.logger

    # Load ActiveMessaging
    ActiveMessaging::load_processors

    # Start it up!
    ActiveMessaging::start

    sleep 10
end
```